# using property name "title" in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

In my c# class, everything was working fine.
My view model properties were exposed correctly.

If I called upon one of the properties in the class I was exposing, let's say "id" or "type", they came out in the emulator fine... if however I tried to access "title", it would not work.

So I thought, maybe some dodgy data, but I couldn't find any... at a last ditch attempt I called title attribute "floppydoodlewoodle" (for lack of a better name) and in my xaml, updated the binding. It worked...

Does this sound right? Some pre taken property name? Or is there something else a bit dodgy going on here?

**EDIT::**

The question was simply if the word title (as a property) is allowed in xaml, but here is the xaml if you really must see it.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ActivityStreamItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5,0,0,0">                
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ttitle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,5" Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Notice I have {Binding ttitle}, I had to change it and the backing data from title to ttitle to make it work (rather than floppydoodlewoodle as previously suggested hehe).

I hope this clarifies things... It's just weird that title doesn't pick up, but using the same data and changing it to ttitle allows it to appear... so I assumed it was just a reserved name in xaml but then again, it's annoying so I thought I best ask.

The other thought was that xaml was having ambiguity issues between other properties... but i'm struggling to see how considering i'm calling this template like so:

```
            <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ActivityStreamList"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ActivityStreamItemTemplate}" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding ActivityStream}" 
                                    Margin="40,0,0,96" 
                                    LayoutMode="List"
                                    HideEmptyGroups="True"
                                    IsGroupingEnabled="True">

            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Here is the relevant ViewModel section. ((***** is just privacy for this post) - AlphaKeyGroup = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

```
private async void LoadActivityStreamSection()
    {
        activityStreamRepository = new *****StreamRepository();
        var tempActivityStream = await activityStreamRepository.GetAllBySpaceId(space.space_id);

        List<AlphaKeyGroup<(*****Stream>> groupedActivityStream = AlphaKeyGroup<(*****Stream>.CreateGroups(tempActivityStream,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
            (*****Stream a) => { return a.ttitle; }, true);

        //activityStream = tempActivityStream;
        activityStream = groupedActivityStream;
        ActivityStream = null;

        //LoadBar loadBar = new LoadBar("Logging in");
        //loadBar.ShowLoadBar(this);
    }
```

Comment: No this has nothing to do with anything. Post your code and XAML and please be specific about your current problem. Property Names are Case Sensitive.

Comment: title is not reserved, but I would advice against using "Name"

Comment: Can you post the xaml and code?

Comment: No can help without the code. This is like man without his heart.

Comment: Okay guys, sorry about lack of code. Hope this clarifies what i'm talking about. (see OP)

Comment: @ShawnKendrot - So you're saying it's definetly some ambiguity in my code. Perhaps by using the AlphaKeyGroup<T> : List<T> class that msdn supplies is getting confused in my code when i'm preparing it for possible grouping in longlistselector.

Comment: @JamesT could you show us model class from the ActivityStream collection?

Comment: What is the type of ActivityStream?

Comment: List<AlphaKeyGroup<(*****Stream>> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Can you show your *****Stream object. Please give it a real name instead of ****. Change it to JamesStream if you need to hide the real name, but please do not use *